# Looping a XML file with XSL and filling in columns of data

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Here is a simplified snippet of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="0" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0">
        <Date ThisWeek="W20171106" NextWeek="W20171113">November 6-12</Date>
        <MeetingDate Day="9" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="11" MonthShort="Nov" MonthFull="November" Year="2017"/>
    </Meeting>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="1" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0">
        <Date ThisWeek="W20171113" NextWeek="W20171120">November 13-19</Date>
        <MeetingDate Day="16" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="11" MonthShort="Nov" MonthFull="November" Year="2017"/>
    </Meeting>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="2" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0">
        <Date ThisWeek="W20171120" NextWeek="W20171127">November 20-26</Date>
        <MeetingDate Day="23" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="11" MonthShort="Nov" MonthFull="November" Year="2017"/>
    </Meeting>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="3" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0">
        <Date ThisWeek="W20171127" NextWeek="W20171204">November 27–December 3</Date>
        <MeetingDate Day="30" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="11" MonthShort="Nov" MonthFull="November" Year="2017"/>
    </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

This is some extracted XSL script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dir">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.css"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Congregation"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" />
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="containerPage">
          <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, up until now, I have always processed each week, one at a time, with the for loop. I essentially create a table of data for week one, then table of data for week two and so on.

Now, one of my users has asked me if they can have a XSL script that would prepare my data in a more condensed manner. Eg:

[image: New Report]

As you can see, he wants to use one column of a table for each week instead. I am not sure how I can go about this. As I create the table and each row (each row being an assignment) I need to fill in the cells, one from each week in the list.

I think I am overcomplicating the explanation of the issue.

Can I navigate my XML with XSL in any way to achieve his desire (without changing the syntax of the XML file)?

## Update

I tried this and I am not even sure if it is the best way to approach it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dir">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.css"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Congregation"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" />
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <!--Date-->
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/Date" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[2]/Date" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[3]/Date" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[4]/Date" />
            </td>
            <!--But there might be a 5th element - How to check?-->
          </tr>
          <!--Process next row-->
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: Results]

As you can see it kind of works but I would need to conditionally have to process a 5th column based on number of items in the list. Don't know how to do that.

In addition I see this having a lot of duplicated code.

I tried using a `xsl:for-each` again. I thought I could pass a `mode`. I thought that would be great then I would know what it is I want to display. But can't pass a `mode`.

Am I going in the right direction and how can it be made more modular?

## Update 2

I tried using the `count` command but I am doing it wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dir">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.css"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Congregation"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" />
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <!--Date-->
          <tr>
            <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[count(*) &gt;= 1]">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[count(*) &gt;= 2]">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[2]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[count(*) &gt;= 3]">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[3]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[count(*) &gt;= 4]">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[4]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[count(*) &gt;= 5]">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[5]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
          </tr>
          <!--Process next row-->
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Update 3

OK, I have worked out how to use the `count` feature correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dir">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.css"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Congregation"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" />
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <!--Date-->
          <tr>
            <xsl:if test="count(MeetingWorkBook/Meeting) &gt;= 1">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(MeetingWorkBook/Meeting) &gt;= 2">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[2]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(MeetingWorkBook/Meeting) &gt;= 3">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[3]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(MeetingWorkBook/Meeting) &gt;= 4">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[4]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(MeetingWorkBook/Meeting) &gt;= 5">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of  select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[5]/Date" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
          </tr>
          <!--Process next row-->
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, the question still remains, is this the most efficient way to do this? I will have to repeat similar code for up to 5 cells on each row. Each row will require I access certain information in the `meeting` node. In the first row I accessed the date. But in the next row, I will be accessing the `Chairman` value.

So can I simplify this so that I only need to type the code for each bit of information once with a template?

I hoe I am making sense here. I just want to get the logic simple and efficient before I add in all the rest of the script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If people are going to negative vote a question of mind can I kindly ask them to take a moment to offer some constructive criticism? Negative votes impact on our reputation so if we have to learn something about what or how we are asking something, a comment is welcome. I feel that more helpful than just a discouraging negative down vote. Thanks.

Comment: Your write up was very good.  Good luck.

Comment: Why do not you use [tag:xpath] instead?

Answer (score 1):

This may be more efficient for you.  Notice I used * in the template match.  So, you can created the next row using the same template.  But, you can also specify Date and create a different template for the next row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dir">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk.css"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Congregation"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" />
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <!--Date-->
          <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting/Date"/>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- column mode-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of  select="." />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```